# two jquery UI boxes with two different text size

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

This is the site i work,

http://cbtallc.com/test-page/#form

On this page, under Date and Time, I have used Jquery datepicker and timepicker. The datepicker is standard datepicker with jquery UI.

And timepicker is a separate code from this site, http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/. It is also based on jquery UI.

I want to know why the text on the timepicker is so much blown up than the one on datepicker.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Karma/style.css, tables font-size is set to 1.2em

```
table{font-size:1.2em;}
```

This is why the timepicker show bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Im using the Jquery Time Picker Plugins here [Jquery Time Picker Plugins](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/) and so far i have no problem.

You can check all the list of jquery plugins here [Jquery Plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/) that I used in web development.

Hope it helps a bit.

Goodluck